# The advantage of / in / to booking tickets in advance is

Tags: prepositions, in-of

Does using "of" with "advantage" consider Bad English?

> There is an advantage **of** abbreviating some things
>   **Bad, ugly English.** [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209593/there-is-an-advantage-in-of-doing-something)

Note: the first example of "advantage" word in [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/advantage) is:

> The **advantage of** booking tickets in advance is that you get better seats.

Comment: See my answer in https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131373/correct-phrase-advantages-in-using-data-or-advantages-of-using-data/133648#133648

Answer (score -2):

1. In booking ahead, (subject) (benefit clause).
2. The benefit of booking ahead is (benefit).

In 1, the subject is the process of booking in advance.
In 2, the subject is the benefit.