# Correct phrase: "advantages in using data" or "advantages of using data"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, formal-language, in-of

Prepositions confuse me. Which is correct: "advantages **in** using data" or "advantages **of** using data"?

Both sound good to me, but which is the correct and formal version?

Comment: The formal version would be 'advantages of using data'

Comment: Similar question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/123646/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct is "**advantages of using data**".

I'm not a native speaker and from what I know, the noun "**[advantage](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/advantage)**" is used this way:

**advantage of**

1. The advantages of doing something *(can precede a gerund)*:

   - He has the **advantage of** speaking English fluently.
2. The advantages of something *(a good or useful feature that something has; a factor or circumstance of benefit to its possessor)*:

   - One of the many **advantages of** living in New York is that you can eat out at almost any time of day.

**advantage in**

3. The advantages in something *(something that benefits the one it belongs to; the fact of being in a better position or condition His great height is an advantage in basketball*):

   - Speed is an **advantage in** sports.
   - His great height is an **advantage in** basketball.

**advantage to**

4. To somebody's advantage to something *(benefit or gain)*:

   - It's **to your own advantage to** study. *(=you would benefit from it)*
   - It would be **to your advantage to agree** to his demands. *(= it would improve the situation for you)*
   - It might be **to your advantage to take** a computer course of some kind. *(=it might help you)*

> Depending on what precedes the word "**advantages**" in your examples, you choose a [corresponding preposition](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/advantage)!